# Plotting Solution to Heat Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, summation, heat-equation

By hand, I've solved the heat equation and looking to 3D plot the solution. My function is
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(nx)e^{-111n^2t}$$
The code I've been trying to use to far is

```
Plot3D[2*Sum[((-1)^n)/(n)Sin[n x]Exp[-111t*n^2],{n,1,Infinity}],
       {x,-Pi,Pi},{t,0,100}]
```

It's been running for a while with no output. Any help would be fab :)

Comment: We can approximate solution,put $\infty \approx 50$, or a bigger number.

Comment: you might also try `NSum` here.

Comment: There are lots of animations of PDE's solutions, all generated using Mathematica with source code used [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/PDE_animations/index.htm) that you can look at. You do not need that many terms really. I normally use few terms and that is enough.

Answer (score 6):

The Gaussian factor in your sum decays extremely quickly. We can thus truncate the sum safely; a naïve way to estimate the truncation limit goes like this:

```
Solve[Exp[-111 t n^2] == 2^-52 (* $MachineEpsilon *) && n > 0, n, Reals] // Simplify
   {{n -> ConditionalExpression[(2 Sqrt[(13 Log[2])/111])/Sqrt[t], t > 0]}}
```

and thus

```
Plot3D[2 Sum[(-1)^n/n Sin[n x] Exp[-111 t n^2],
             {n, 1, Ceiling[2 Sqrt[13 Log[2]/(111 t)]]}],
       {x, -π, π}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Very nice analysis of the truncation limit. Also limit `t` to much shorter times, to see where the solution is significant.  `Plot3D[2 Sum[(-1)^n/n Sin[n x] Exp[-111 t n^2], {n, 1, Ceiling[2 Sqrt[13 Log[2]/(111 t)]]}], {x, -π, π}, {t, 0, 1/10}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 8, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, t, z}, Abs[z] > 10^-3]] `

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* is trying to evaluate the infinite sum, that's why it taking so long.

Why not try Partial sum?

```
Clear[n, t, x]

f[x_, t_, nn_] := 2*Sum[((-1)^n)/(n) Sin[n x] Exp[-111 t*n^2], {n, 1, nn}]

Plot3D[f[x, t, 100], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, 1000}]
```

Now, try different values for `nn` (large ones).

Answer (score 2):

If you are into animation, you can speed things with Compile.

Function to plot without the summation.

```
function = (2/n)*(-1)^n*Sin[n*x]*Exp[-111*n^2*t]
```

Get it into pure function form

```
un = Function[n, #] &@function;
```

Compile the function summed for n terms.

```
usum[n_] := Compile[{x, t}, #] &@Total@un@Range[1, n]
```

Pick a number of terms for plotting.

```
u = usum[50];


Animate[Plot[u[x, t], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, PlotLabel -> t*"t"], {t, 0, 0.05}]
```

[image]

The solution damps out quickly with that form of exponential term.